# iOS 13.2.3 pdfViewGestureRecognize and PDFkit

Tags: ios13, xcode11, pdfkit, pdfview, ios13.2

Here is my Code it work perfectly in iOS 12 but for iOS 13 code can't give exactly values

```
let pdfViewGestureRecognizer = PDFViewGestureRecognizer()

 pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey: 20])

        pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(pdfViewGestureRecognizer)

        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
```

here is first problem is not go here I adding great delegate for Gesture and other details find here but isn't work too !! isn't go to func touchesBegan and is not go to if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIView") != nil)

```
class PDFViewGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    var isTracking = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    isTracking = true
    print ("but not iOS 13.2.3")


}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    isTracking = false


}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    isTracking = false
}
```

}

here is second part

```
        let pdfSubVws = pdfView.subviews
        print("subVws  ",pdfSubVws)

        for subVws in pdfSubVws
        {
            if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIPageViewControllerContentView") != nil)
            {
                let pageVc = subVws.subviews

                for subVws in pageVc
                {
                    if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIQueuingScrollView") != nil)
                    {
                        let QueueVc = subVws.subviews
//                        print("QueueVcQueueVc  ", QueueVc)
                        for subVws in QueueVc
                        {
                            if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIView") != nil)
                            {
                                let viewVc = subVws.subviews
//                                print("\n\nviewVcVcQueueVc  ", viewVc)

                                for subVws in viewVc
                                {
                                    if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIView") != nil)
                                    {

                                        let SubviewVc = subVws.subviews
//                                        print("\n\nSubviewVcSubviewVc  ", SubviewVc)

                                        for subVws in SubviewVc
                                        {
                                            if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIScrollView") != nil)
                                            {
                                                let finalVw = subVws.subviews
//                                                print("\n\nfinalVw  ", finalVw)
//
                                                for subVws in finalVw
                                                {
                                                    if (String(describing: subVws).range(of:"UIView") != nil)   //here is  ok iOS 12 It's ok  but not iOS 13.2.3
                                                    {
```